# Как добавить несколько массивов сразу в документ MongoDB с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, массивы, mongodb

Я хочу добавить 2ва массива сразу в базу данных Mongo DB

Для того чтобы добавть 1н массив в массив phone, я использовал команду:

```
$col->update(array("email"=>$email), array('$addToSet'=>array(
"phone" =>  array("id" => "3","no" => "+1 000 0000","name" => "Bob"))));
```

Пример документа

```
"_id": "id",
"email": "Name@google.com",
"phone": [
 {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Bob",
  "no": "+1 000 0000",
 },
 {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Bob",
  "no": "+1 000 0000",
 }
]
```

Я пытался добавить сразу 2 массива в массив phone

```
$col->update(array("email"=>$email), array('$addToSet'=>array("phone" => 
array(("id" => "6","name" => "Bob","no" => "+1 000 0000"),
("id" => "7","name" => "Bob","no" => "+1 000 0000")))));
```

Но у меня выскакивает синтаксическая ошибка. Примеров как добавить 1н массив с несколькими значениями операторами $addToSet и $each в интернете полно а вот как добавить сразу несколько массивов примеров нет.

Answer (score 0):

Понял как это сделать, если кому понадобиться в будущем вот результат:

```
$col->update(array("email"=>$email),array('$addToSet' => array(
 'phone' => array('$each' =>
 [(Object) array("id" => "6","name" => "Bob1","no" => "Bob1"),
  (Object) array("id" => "7","name" => "Bob2","no" => "Bob1"),]))));
```